# Why is call by value slower than call by const reference for short arguments in trivial functions?

Tags: c++, gcc

Conventional wisdom seems to suggest that short arguments(`sizeof(X) <= 16`) should be passed by value instead of `const&` as values can be passed in registers, while references are implemented as pointers and force a memory access. I tried to quantify this difference with a short test:

struct.h:

```
struct X
{
unsigned long fill=0;
unsigned long x=0;
};
```

functions.cpp:

```
bool struct_by_value(X x)
{
    return x.x < 17;
}

bool struct_by_cref(X const& x)
{
    return x.x < 17;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    size_t N = 1UL << 32;
    X x;
    double diff = 0;
    auto start = clk::now();
    for (unsigned long i; i < N; i++){
        struct_by_cref(x);
    }
    auto end = clk::now();
    std::cout << "cref: " << secs(end-start) << std::endl;    
    start = clk::now();
    for (unsigned long i; i < N; i++){
        struct_by_value(x);
    }
    end = clk::now();
    std::cout << "value: " << secs(end-start) << std::endl;
 
    start = clk::now();
    for (x.x = 0; x.x < N; x.x++){
        struct_by_cref(x);
    }
    end = clk::now();
    std::cout << "cref: " << secs(end-start) << std::endl;    

    start = clk::now();
    for (x.x = 0; x.x < N; x.x++){
        struct_by_value(x);
    }
    end = clk::now();
    std::cout << "value: " << secs(end-start) << std::endl;
 }
```

indeed `struct_by_value` compiles (`g++-12.2.0 -O2`) to

```
_Z15struct_by_value1X:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    cmp rsi, 16
    setbe   al
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

while `struct_by_cref` gives me

```
_Z14struct_by_crefRK1X:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    cmp QWORD PTR 8[rdi], 16
    setbe   al
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

with an obvious memory access. But when I run the compiled code on my machine (`i7-10850H`)
i get about 6.5 seconds for

```
 for (unsigned long i; i < N; i++){
        struct_by_cref(x);
    }
```

and

```
    for (unsigned long i; i < N; i++){
    struct_by_value(x);
}
```

with run to run variations larger than the differences between value and reference. But for

```
for (x.x = 0; x.x < N; x.x++){
    struct_by_cref(x);
}
```

and

```
for (x.x = 0; x.x < N; x.x++){
    struct_by_value(x);
}
```

I get about 7.2 and 7.4 seconds respectively, with call by value consistently slower by about 0.2 seconds.

The question is why?

The first test seems simple to explain:
As the struct never changes and branch prediction in a long, tight loop is good the loads can be issued in advance, and as memory throughput and execution ports are far from beeing saturated, this does not cause any overhead and there should be no difference between call-by-value and call-by-cref.

But the second test baffels me:
For call by const reference, during each iteration `x.x` has to be written to memory in the `main` function, and then read again in in `struct_by_cref`, while for `struct_by_value` the whole struct can stay in registers. There can't be any prefetching of the value from memory as it is only written imedeatly before the load. Is there some shortcut where the cpu replaces consecutive stores and loads from to and from memory with a move between registers? But why is the call by value version slower? Here everything should stay in registers by default.

Comment: First question: What optimizations, if any, are you using when compiling and testing? Just `-O2`? Why not `-O3`? Additionally "references are implemented as pointers and force a memory access" is speculation. Is that a certainty?

Comment: "*while references are implemented as pointers and force a memory access*" - not necessarily. A reference is just an *alias* to an object, it *may* be implemented as a pointer, but it is not *required* to be. That is up to the compiler to decide. The compiler is perfectly free to use a register to hold a reference if it wants to. This is an implementation detail, not dictated by the standard.

Comment: @RemyLebeau But it is required by the ABI: https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#reference-parameters

Comment: @Artyer sure, for that 1 particular ABI, but not all ABIs work that same way.

Comment: @Artyer and some optimisation may even transform the program in many ways...

Comment: I remember when Stroustrup was asked this question: *”if references will be implemented as pointers, why add the feature? thereby creating a divergence from C”* and he said not at all. [A Reference is an alias (an alternate name) for an object](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#). Good anecdote though, take a reference when ever you can, only take a pointer if compelled.

Comment: The conventional wisdom will vary by platform, and conditions.  The cross-over on my platform is 256 bytes of parameters where pass-by-value parameters (assuming cache co-located) are a win over pass-by-reference.  sizeof(X) ≤ 16 should be solid pass-by-value win on all platforms.  But that's just a rule of thumb; the proof is in the **profiling** pudding — and that has to be with optimizations enabled to be meaningful.